# Auth::attempt returns true, but redirects to other page and returns guest

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-authentication

Why does my `Auth::attempt` return false when refreshing or redirecting to another page?

Below is my controller; I'm using Laravel 5.8. I was using `Auth::logingUsingId()` and it's the same; it returns false if refreshed or redirecting to another page.

```
Auth::attempt([
    'email' => $request->email,
    'password' => $request->password,
    'activation_status' => '1'
]);

return redirect('/user');
```

Comment: If you are using multiple guard then `Auth::guard('admin')->attempt...`or you can put a `Auth::check()` on redirection URL

Answer (score 0):

i was doing the exact same thing today ... my own login and register routes ... i had to add `$request->session()->regenerate();` after the attemp method. Hope it helps.